# Three.js skybox texture issue

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to create a simple Skybox using Three.js but have run into an issue with the texture I'm applying to the cube only working on the outside, and not displaying on the inside of the cube.

Here's my skybox code:

```
var path = assetPath + skyboxPrefix;
var urls = [ path + 'alpine_front.jpg',
             path + 'alpine_back.jpg',
             path + 'alpine_left.jpg',
             path + 'alpine_right.jpg',
             path + 'alpine_top.jpg' ];

var cubeTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );

var shader = THREE.ShaderUtils.lib["cube"];
shader.uniforms["tCube"].texture = cubeTexture;

var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
    uniforms        : shader.uniforms,
    fragmentShader  : shader.fragmentShader,
    vertexShader    : shader.vertexShader,
    depthWrite      : false
} );

var skyboxGeom = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 10000, 10000, 10000 );

skybox = new THREE.Mesh( skyboxGeom, skyboxMaterial );
skybox.flipSided = true;
    
scene.add(skybox);
```

Here's a live version http://projects.harrynorthover.com/landscape/src/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`object.flipSided` has been gone since r50. It got replaced with `object.material = THREE.BackSide`. Checking [updated examples that use the same feature](http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_materials_cubemap.html) and also this [migration](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Migration) page should be handy on cases like this.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help mrdoob, that worked a treat cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I've also seen the "flipSided" switch in other examples and didn't get it to work (might be outdated). What works for me (with a sphere) is setting a negative scale:

```
skybox.scale.x = -1;
```

Comment: Just given this a try and all I get is a blank screen, texture still isn't displaying.